# VBA code is asking for macro name when I try to run it

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code for selecting multiple names in the data validation!
It keeps telling me that I need to enter macro name to run it.
Any ideas why?

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' To allow multiple selections in a Drop Down List in Excel (without repetition)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Column = 10 Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Macro should have ran, but it keeps throwing me an error!

Comment: Your `Sub` has a parameter/argument. You cannot run it by pressing `F5`. That code is an event, so trigger the event by changing something. Put a breakpoint (F9) on the first line so it wil pause there and then make a change to a cell. This assumes you have the code in the right place and not in a module.

Comment: how about putting the code inside the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub

` of your desired sheet

Comment: @braX the brakepoint works but I have to reset it everytime I wanna run it

Comment: @k1dr0ck I have put the code in the desired sheet, its still giving off the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs without asking for a macro name on my PC. As others have noted, put it on the code page for the sheet being modified.

As a side note, your `Application.EnableEvents = True` is redundant. When the function runs normally, it continues past the `Exitsub:` statement, and will hit the second `Application.EnableEvents = True` statement. Program flow will not exit a sub before entering an error handler unless explicitly told to exit.

Better would be this. Both error and normal flow will execute the statement in this case:

```
  End If
ErrorHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Notice I changed the name of the target from `Exitsub:` to `ErrorHandler:` to avoid confusion. It's easily confused with the `Exit Sub` statement, but doesn't cause exiting the sub. That might explain why you thought normal flow would exit before the error handler.